# How to determine if a Label date is 3 months in the past

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view that has a date field that is a Label.
I want to find out if that date is 3 months in the past from the current date. 
I am executing this on the `DataBound` event. 
Here is my snippet:

```
protected void gvcmi_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label LastVisitLbl = (Label)e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("lblStatusv");
        If (LastVisitLbl /*not sure what to put here*/)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck on what I should put in the second If.

Comment: The text of the Label represents a date? If yes, which format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the label's Text to a `DateTime` variable using `DateTime.TryParse` and then compare it to `DateTime.Now` minus 3 months:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(LastVisitLbl.Text, out date))
{
     if (date < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
     {
          // Do Something
     }
}
else
   // Error - the label's format is not a correct DateTime
```

Comment: Maybe you should convert the date with `DateTime.TryParse`. So no exception are thrown.

Comment: `if(DateTime.TryParse(LastVisitLbl.Text, out date))`:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx). As you are rendering those label you can trust that dates are in the right format so you could just use `ParseExact`

```
protected void gvcmi_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label LastVisitLbl = (Label)e.Row.Cells[7].FindControl("lblStatusv");
            If (DateTime.ParseExact(LastVisitLbl.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat) >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        }
}
```

Where `dd/MM/yyyy` is the format you know the date was rendered.